# Interface Go with C libraries

Tags: c, binding, go

How does one interface a Go program with a C library?

I've been browsing Go's source code but I still didn't figured it out. If someone has already done so, could you share, please?

**UPDATED:** Thanks to @fserb, I am posting some documentation from the Go sources:

> Cgo enables the creation of Go
>   packages that call C code.
>
> Usage: cgo [compiler options] file.go
>
> The compiler options are passed
>   through uninterpreted when invoking
>   gcc to compile the C parts of the
>   package.
>
> The input file.go is a syntactically
>   valid Go source file that imports the
>   pseudo-package "C" and then refers to
>   types such as C.size_t, variables such
>   as C.stdout, or functions such as
>   C.putchar.
>
> If the import of "C" is immediately
>   preceded by a comment, that comment is
>   used as a header when compiling the C
>   parts of the package.  For example:
>
> ```
> // #include <stdio.h>
> // #include <errno.h>
> import "C"
> ```
>
> Cgo transforms the input file into
>   four output files: two Go source
>   files, a C file for 6c (or 8c or 5c),
>   and a C file for gcc.
>
> The standard package makefile rules in
>   Make.pkg automate the process of using
>   cgo.  See $GOROOT/misc/cgo/stdio and
>   $GOROOT/misc/cgo/gmp for examples.
>
> Cgo does not yet work with gccgo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/). Also, take a look at misc/cgo/gmp on the Go source code for an example code on how to wrap a C library in Go.