# Why does Go not seem to recognize size_t in a C header file?

Tags: c, go

I am trying to write a go library that will act as a front-end for a C library. If one of my C structures contains a `size_t`, I get compilation errors. AFAIK `size_t` is a built-in C type, so why wouldn't go recognize it?

My header file looks like:

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    char *      buffer;
    size_t      buffer_size;
    size_t *    length;
} mystruct;
```

and the errors I'm getting are:

```
gcc failed:
In file included from <stdin>:5:
mydll.h:4: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'size_t'

on input:

typedef struct { char *p; int n; } _GoString_;
_GoString_ GoString(char *p);
char *CString(_GoString_);
#include "mydll.h"
```

I've even tried adding `// typedef unsigned long size_t` or `// #define size_t unsigned long` in the .go file before the `#include`, and then I get "gcc produced no output".

I have seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760468/interface-go-with-c-libraries) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go), and looked over the [example](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/misc/cgo/gmp/gmp.go?r=release) with no success.

Comment: The `_t` prefix on `size_t` tells you that it is *not* an intrinsic C type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem was solved by adding the `#include <stddef.h>` - thanks Ken and Georg.

The second problem was that my Go code was using `mydll.mystruct` rather than `C.mystruct`, so the C package was not being used at all. There was a bug in the cgo compiler that displayed this error message when the C package was imported and not used. The cgo bug has been fixed (by someone else) to give a more useful error message.

Details are [here](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/46ff9264cc40a8db#).

Answer (score 10):

As per C99, *§7.17*, `size_t` is not a builtin type but defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

In MSC, size_t is defined (among other places) in STDDEF.H. I'd suspect that's where you'll find it in gcc as well, so you'll need to add a reference to that header in your library (DLL) source.

Comment: I added `#include <stddef.h>` to the .h file and got "gcc produced no output". I changed the `<>` to `""` and got the same thing. Then I put it the .go file in front of `// #include "mydll.h"` and again got the same thing. I'm using gcc 4.1.2, if it matters.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow:  You are now probably trying to run gcc just on header files or on .c files with no actual (non-static or inline) code.

Comment: @nategoose: I added a function with a body in the .h file and called it from the go file. Same result.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow: You don't add "function with body" to the .h file. You declare it in the .h file, implement it in the corresponding .c source, and then use the function in your application or DLL. If you don't actually use (call) the function from code that can execute, the linker doesn't include it.